# Ansible ssh-add on osx with entering passphrase

Tags: macos, ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

I am planning to create an ansible playbook to provision multiple Apple Mac build machines.
Currently, I am stumbling upon the following issue when trying to add out github ssh key to the keychain.

```
- name: add ssh-key
  shell: |
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Running `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` on the target machine will obviously ask for the passphrase like so:

`Enter passphrase for /Users/wooga/.ssh/id_rsa:`

However, I could not find any way to provide the passphrase via ansible.
Is there any solution to this problem other than using passphrase-less ssh keys?

Best,
Patrick

Comment: This question has a radical misunderstanding of how ssh-agent works

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: When you run `shell:`, the items started by that session will die when the `shell:` disconnects, unless you guard the processes it created with `nohup`. But, even that won't help what **you** are trying to do because unless you are connecting to the target machine as the ultimate login user, the `ssh-agent` spawned will belong to the ansible connecting user, and will not be trusted by the login user. Even if it's the _same_ login, it still might not be trusted cause it's a different tty (that would require running some experiments); therefore, what you're trying to do is suspicious

Comment: That's to say **nothing** of the fact that what you _said_ is that you want to add the github ssh key to the keychain, but ssh-agent has zero to do with the Apple KeyChain and is managed by an entirely different process

Comment: Your question keeps getting better and better: I looked up what `ssh-add -K` does -- so, are you pluging in a USB stick into the target machines and asking `ssh-add` to load the key from it?! because that's a super weird use of ansible

Comment: Hey @mdaniel
I am not sure where you looked up the -K option and what it has to do with a USB stick. This is the official man page & the `-K` option is special to OSX:

`When adding identities, each passphrase will also be stored in the user's keychain.  When removing identities with -d, each passphrase will be removed from it.`


This is exactly what I am trying to do - Provisioning a Mac build machine running OSX and want this ssh key to be added to the ssh-agent & the passphrase to be stored in the keychain.